# How to skip the test on template on jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I have the follow code that I want to test with jest I have successfully made a test for methods and data in script tag. The problem is I have a nuxt-link component in my template tag that gets called in jest which causes me errors.

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="result-display-area">
        <nuxt-link to="sample_link">
          sample link
        </nuxt-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async function1() {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: How exactly do you test? You can avoid this by using `shallowMount` or `stubs` option. This is actually a preferable way to do unit tests with third-party libs.

Comment: shallow mount still throws error about nuxt-link and other random things like b-card (from bootstrap)